# What is wrong with my javascript recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

What is wrong with this recursion function?
fac(5) gives NaN

```
function fac(num){
  while(num>2){
    return(num*fac(num-1))
  }
}
```

Comment: Coz you haven't handled `num <= 2`. So at some point your code will multiply the `number` with `undefined`

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu add this as an answer so the question could be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fac(1)` returns nothing, which is `undefined`, and `undefined*1` is `NaN`, that's why.

Change your code to

```
function fac(num){
  return num>2 ? num*fac(num-1) : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way should be:

```
function fact(num) {
    if(num > 2)
        return num * fact(num - 1);
    else
        return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

NaN - not a number error , occurs usually but not limited to when we try to apply a numerical operation to a value which is not a number.

The Issue at hand is when the input value is less than 2 , the function return `undefined`, which is not a number, so the `return (num*fac(num-1))` will fail due to `num * undefined`.
to fix this , we have to return a value when number is 2 or less than 2.

```
function fact(num) {
    if(num > 2)
        return num * fact(num - 1);
    else
        return num;
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence might make people think applying a numerical operation on numbers doesn't produce NaN. Please fix it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, have corrected the sentence to depict the same

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with your code

```
function fac(num){
  while(num>2){
    return(num*fac(num-1))
  }
}
```

- No return value for `num <= 2`. So, at some point your code will multiply `Number` with `undefined` which results in `NaN`
- `while` loop is not needed

```js
function fac(num) {
    return (num > 2) ? num * fac(num - 1) : 1;
}

alert(fac(5));
```